# Change class of element using javascript

Tags: javascript, onchange, html-select

I'm having difficulties to change class of element based on selected item in `select` tag. This is my code:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <select onchange="wow(this.value)">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>            
        </select>
    </tr>               
    <tr id="x" class="show">
        x
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
function wow(value){
    switch(value){
        case "a": document.getElementById("x").className = "show"; break;       
        case "b": document.getElementById("x").className = "hide"; break;
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.show{
    display:inline-block;
}

.hide{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

I don't see any problem here. I also tried `setAttribute("class", "show")` but doesn't work.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive that's a jQuery example.

Comment: You're missing the `case` part of a switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to wrap `X` in a [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/td):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CVxP7/

```
<tr>...<td id="x" class="show">x</td></tr>
```

Also you have to add `case` in front of `"a":`

```
case "a":
    document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", "show");
    break;
```

---

PS: There is a more efficient way to achieve what you are trying to do here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CVxP7/2/

```
function wow(value) {
    var index = {
        a: "show",
        b: "hide"
    };
    document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", index[value]);
}
```

Now you don't need to type `document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class"...` twice.

Comment: it works, thanks, but why I can't put class in <tr> ?

Comment: @shankshera - Technically you can, but it is a good habit to [wrap your content with `<th>` or `<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
switch(value){
    case "a": document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", show); break;        
    case "b": document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", hide); break;
}
```

Comment: `show` is not defined.